Grid with different height and same spacing

ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
    ForEach(0..<3) { i in
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<2) { j in
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    LearnCellView()
                        .frame(width: 164, height: 240)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(20)
}
.padding(15)

With above code I've achieved normal grid but I want to create the grid as shown in image. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated. There is no exact double height or grid item it is uneven and I want same vertical and horizontal space in grid.

You could try using two VStack inside an HStack instead. See also Grid Item should have Dynamic Height in SwiftUI
